# CSS: Transition of horizontal scroll menu is not smooth

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to make the transition of the menu to be smooth. The problem is when you click the arrows, the 2nd div will show on the bottom of the 1st div, making it not smooth to look at. pls see below for my code:

Pls see my code here:
http://www.codeply.com/go/mdMPOkmFVH

Comment: It was an interesting question :) @R. C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code you need to do some basic change in CSS, your CSS should be as follows

```
.btn-arrow {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
.effects-list {
    text-align: center;
}
.col-xs-4 {
    min-height:20px;
}
```

Here you need to set minimum height 20px for class .col-xs-4, The reason behind this is the jquery function needs to set sliding element to have position absolute, and you were setting it to relative by force. and if all child elements in divs are absolute elements, then absolute elements won't acquire it's space in parent div and that is why it will make parent div's acquired content will be empty. so it will treat it as empty div and set it's height as 0px, and won't show anything in the div... so here we are specifying it's minimum height to solve  our issue.

Another thing that we could have done is adding white space to the parent div
e.g.

```
<div class="col-xs-4" id="effects_menu">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your reply. I tried doing what you post. But the div for the menu is not inline with the Prev and Next link. I want it to be inline.

Comment: Oh ok, I got confused. I removed the position: relative and it's working now :) Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @R.C. Cheers, i forgot to add jsfiddle otherwise you might have cracked this fast... 